# data-target not working for dropdown menus in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have index.html as home webpage with fixed nav-bar and i used scrollspy to navigate menu items. I created one other webpage with same nav-bar as in index.html page, now i like to link this second webpage menu's in dropdown with scrollspy div ID of home webpage i.e. in index.html page. My index.html file as like,

```
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
 <!-- navigation bar -->
 <div id="navigationbar">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <ul><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <strong>COMPANY</strong></a></ul>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 </div>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
 <ul class="nav menu nav navbar-nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class=""><a href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only"></span>            </a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="abc.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
         <li id="dp1"><a href="#pilot">menu1</a></li>
         <li id="dp2"><a href="#design">menu2</a></li>
       </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#in-touch">social</a></li>  
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="pilot"><p>div1></p></div>
  <div id="design"><p>div2></p></div>
  <div id="contact"><p>div3></p></div>
  <div id="social"><p>div4></p></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now I have another webpage with same navigation bar and I like to call that id elements from index.html page to this second web page, for that, I have given data-target as below which works for nav-bar menus but not working for drop-down menus but still not working,

working for contact tab-

contact

but not working for dropdown
    menu1

is there any solution...?